# Invalidate vs Update

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, invalidation

I have code that lets be drag around a borderless form in winforms that I've been using for several months now, which works extremely well.

But when I first was given the code, they used `this.Invalidate();` in the `MouseMove` event of the Form, and the Form flickered a little and was slow when dragging around. So, I replaced `Invalidate()` with `Update()` in the `MouseMove` event and, to my surprise, the Form can now be dragged very smoothly and has no flickering whatsoever.

Can somebody explain to me why Update makes the code work better than Invalidate, even when Invalidate sounds like it's the right one to be using?

Thanks :)

P.S. Maybe it would help more if I added the code... Adding it now.

**Edit** - Here's the code:

---

```
private void titlebar_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.IsMouseDown = true;

    this.LastCursorPosition = new Point(e.X, e.Y);

    if (this.BackColor == Color.White)
    {
        this.BackColor = Color.GhostWhite;
        tbox.BackColor = Color.GhostWhite;
        tbox.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }
    else
    {
        this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(20, 20, 20);
        tbox.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(20, 20, 20);
        tbox.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }
}

private void titlebar_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.IsMouseDown == true)
    {
        //Move the form
        this.Location = new Point(this.Left - (this.LastCursorPosition.X - e.X), this.Top - (this.LastCursorPosition.Y - e.Y));

        // Update works better than Invalidate();.
        Update();
    }
}

private void titlebar_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.IsMouseDown = false;
    this.BackColor = fc;
    tbox.BackColor = fc;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Invalidate marks the window as needing to be refreshed (at some point). Update does it there and then if I remember correctly

Here is a [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/subhagpo/archive/2005/02/22/378098.aspx) to explain the difference better than I'd be able to

Answer (score 41):

`Invalidate()` simply *adds* a region to the update region of the control. The next time WM_PAINT is received, the area you invalidated plus any other invalidated regions, are marked for painting. When `RedrawWindow()` is called, that will normally post a WM_PAINT message to the application queue. The system is free to do what it wants with that, usually more pressing business, and paint when it can.

If you call `Update()`, you get GDI+'s `UpdateWindow()` which won't mark a region for repainting, but pushes a `WM_PAINT` directly to `WNDPROC()`, bypassing the application queue.

If you *need* an immediate refresh of a control, use `Refresh()`, which invalidates the region then immediately calls `Update()`.

Comment: I realize this is an old post and perhaps this should be posted as a separate question, but I'm not clear on when you would use Update and when you would use Refresh.  It seems like both force an immediate repaint.  Are you able to clarify?  Thanks!

Comment: @AdamPlocher From the method comments it would appear that `Invalidate()` simply flags the region as requiring painting, but does not necessarily paint. `Update()` forces any currently invalid regions to repaint, but does not flag anything. And `Refresh()` wraps the two operations together, first flagging the control's region as invalid and then immediately requesting the region be updated (repainted). **Edit:** http://stackoverflow.com/a/952964/1718702