# Trying to draw an image to a form, but not refreshing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

We are using graphics context of a form to draw an image.  However it works fine on initial paint but the image is not being updated unless we set a breakpoint and run it in debug mode, stepping through each time.

What is a good way of making a seperate thread to paint on to a form every second?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a thread. Just call Invalidate() on your form when a meaningful change in status has occurred (or from a timer).

Also see [How do I call paint event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952906/how-do-i-call-paint-event/952964#952964)

Comment: Thank you.

We had to select a region to invalidate. (forgot about the invalidate jazz )

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of your exact scenario but you may be after `Application.DoEvents`.

Comment: Justin, DoEvents() should be avoided as much as possible.