# Manually Calling Paint Event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-4.0, user-controls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I call paint event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952906/how-do-i-call-paint-event)

I have a user custom user control which draws some text on its `paint` event.
I am adding this control to a form and at the same time I’m setting the position of the control.

The problem I am having is the paint event doesn’t get fired unless I set the `dock style` to fill. But I don’t need the dock style to be filled.
Is there any way that I can fire the paint event of control manually?

Also any suggestion why the paint event doesn't fire automatically and get fired when the dock style is filled?

Thanks

Comment: _the paint event doesn’t get fired unless I set the dock style to fill_ - that is a bug somewhere that you need to fix.

Comment: can you not "invalidate" the control? I believe this prompts would lead to the control being redrawn which I would guess would lead to a Paint

Comment: @Pete: Yes, I did try the **invalidate** but it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Control.Invalidate();
```

or

```
Control.Refresh();
```

To force a direct paint event