# Losing graphic shapes after form minimizing C#

Tags: c#, gdi+

After form minimzing my graphic shapes are losing.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 6):

My psychic debugging skills tell me that you're drawing using `CreateGraphics()`.

You need to draw all of your graphics in the `Paint` event so that they get redrawn whene the form gets repainted.

You should never draw using  `CreateGraphics()`.

Comment: Yes, I have drawn using CreateGraphics, because I need to paint shapes on the button click. How can I get PaintEvntArgs on the button click?

Comment: @dotNet_d19: You can't.  You need to draw **in the paint event** so that it can redraw at will.  Instead, you need to keep track of what to draw on every paint and call `Invalidate()`.

Comment: Can you explain in detail? I must draw on the button click, because I set the count of shapes from form.

Comment: Basically you keep the information about what to draw at **Class** level (a List<Something> might be helpful!).  Then, in the `Paint()` event, use the supplied Graphics via `e.Graphics` and iterate over the information in your class level variable and draw everything.  I already gave you an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17384089/2330053) in your **previous** question.  Just follow that basic model...it doesn't have to be a GraphicsPath in the List, you can create a custom Class to represent whatever needs to be drawn.