# Adding a circular button to a Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, button, colors

I have created a circular button in a Windows Form. The button is fine. Only problem is that I want it to be a different color to the background so i set the BackColor to goldenRod. However, it simply creates a "goldenRod" cube around the circular button...how do i make it so that only the button is colored?

```
public MainForm(){

    InitializeComponent();      
    myButtonObject start = new myButtonObject();
    EventHandler myHandler = new EventHandler(start_Click);
    start.Click += myHandler;
    start.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 5);
    start.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(101, 101);
    start.BackColor=System.Drawing.Color.Goldenrod;
    this.Controls.Add(start);
`}

void start_Click(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Start");
}

public class myButtonObject : UserControl
{
    // Draw the new button. 
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
        Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Black);
        // Draw the button in the form of a circle
        graphics.DrawEllipse(myPen, 0, 0, 100, 100);
        myPen.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 @LarsTech, you also need to reset the `BackColor` otherwise it will fill the `UserControl` bounds as that color. Alternatively override the `OnPaintBackground` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fill the `Ellipse` you are drawing during the `OnPaint()` method.

```
graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Goldenrod, new Rectangle(0,0,100,100));
graphics.DrawEllipse(myPen, 0, 0, 100, 100);
```

Then make sure to remove the `start.BackColor` property from your `MainForm()` constructor.

Comment: graphics.DrawEllipse(myPen, 0, 0, 100, 100);
graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Goldenrod, new Rectangle(0,0,100,100));
myPen.Dispose();

Comment: That's exactly what I posted.  Works for me on a test form.

Comment: Do the Fill before the Draw to avoid erasing the outline.

Comment: @user3541263 Edited my answer, you need to remove the `BackColor` property from the button in your form.  The `FillEllipse` will take care of that for you.

Comment: i did as LarsTech said and the outline was retained but i still get the goldenRod cube?

Comment: Wow...u guys are gr8 :) got rid of the BackColor prop and it works :) thnx so much

Comment: how do i mark it as the answer? i'm a newbie here...sorry :P

Answer (score 0):

The BackColor will change the color of the user control rectangle, based on the provided `Size` and `Location`. As Evan stated, you need to use `FillEllipse` instead to create a filled circle - the `DrawEllipse` only draws an outline of the circle.

Here is a full solution to the "circular button" problem, combining the OP's form with Evan's answer and handling of hover events.

```cs
public class MainForm
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ClickableCircle circle = new ClickableCircle(center: new Point(150, 150), radius: 50);
        circle.Click += circle_Click;
        Controls.Add(circle);
    }

    private void circle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Clicked the circle!");
    }
}

class ClickableCircle : UserControl
{
    public readonly Point Center;
    public readonly int Radius;

    public ShapeColoring DefaultColoring { get; set; } = new ShapeColoring()
    {
        Outline = Color.Black,
        Fill = Brushes.Black,
    };

    public ShapeColoring HoverColoring { get; set; } = new ShapeColoring()
    {
        Outline = Color.DarkGray,
        Fill = Brushes.DarkGray,
    };

    private ShapeColoring _coloring = new ShapeColoring();

    public ClickableCircle(Point center, int radius)
    {
        Radius = radius;
        Center = center;
        Location = new Point(x: center.X - radius, y: center.Y - radius);
        Size = new Size(radius * 2, radius * 2);
        _coloring = DefaultColoring;
        MouseEnter += ClickableCircle_MouseEnter;
        MouseLeave += ClickableCircle_MouseLeave;
    }

    private void ClickableCircle_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        ChangeColoring(HoverColoring);
    }

    private void ClickableCircle_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        ChangeColoring(DefaultColoring);
    }

    private void ChangeColoring(ShapeColoring newColoring)
    {
        _coloring = newColoring;
        Refresh();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
        Pen pen = new Pen(_coloring.Outline);
        try
        {
            Rectangle ellipse = new Rectangle(
                x: 0, // relative to the top-left of this user control, not the whole form
                y: 0,
                // adjust width and height so the outline doesn't get cut off
                width: Size.Width - 1,
                height: Size.Height - 1
            );
            graphics.FillEllipse(_coloring.Fill, ellipse);
            graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, ellipse);
        }
        finally { pen.Dispose(); }
    }
}

class ShapeColoring
{
    public Color Outline { get; set; } = Color.White;
    public Brush Fill { get; set; } = Brushes.White;
}
```

[image: default state]

After hovering over the circle with the mouse, the cursor changes to a hand and the circle changes color:

[image: state when hovering with mouse]

## Notes

There were a lot of nuances I had to experiment on to discover:

- The location and size can be set inside the circle class constructor.
- The x/y location of the ellipse in the `OnPaint` method is relative to the circle, not the window.
- If you want to change the color, you need to call `Refresh()` to instantly redraw - see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952964/10792235).
- The `width` and `height` of the ellipse needs to be 1 pixel less than the full size to prevent the outline from getting cut off.

Comment: Side-note: The click/hover events apply to the **user control**, *not* to the circle - so clicking/hovering in the corners outside of the circle will still raise those events.

Comment: Additional note: If you want a thicker border for the outline, use two `FillEllipse` calls instead of using `DrawEllipse`. Fill the outer one first, then the inner one.