# Draw a Circle on a C# PictureBox

Tags: c#, system.drawing

Hi I'm using the code below to draw a circle on a pictureBox, The problem is I don't know why some times if I draw a circle it whon show until I draw an other, some times it will show on the first circle.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private bool isMoving = false;
    private Point mouseDownPosition = Point.Empty;
    private Point mouseMovePosition = Point.Empty;
    private List<Tuple<Point, Point>> lines = new List<Tuple<Point, Point>>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // 
        // pictureBox1
        // 
        this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
        this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(231, 235);
        this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
        this.pictureBox1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.pictureBox1_Paint);
        this.pictureBox1.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBox1_MouseDown);
        this.pictureBox1.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBox1_MouseMove);
        this.pictureBox1.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBox1_MouseUp);
        this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var g = e.Graphics;
        if (isMoving)
        {
            g.Clear(pictureBox1.BackColor);
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, mouseDownPosition, mouseMovePosition);
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, line.Item1, line.Item2);
            }
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        isMoving = true;
        mouseDownPosition = e.Location;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isMoving)
        {
            mouseMovePosition = e.Location;
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isMoving)
        {
            lines.Add(Tuple.Create(mouseDownPosition, mouseMovePosition));
        }
        isMoving = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Refresh()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952964/1718702) instead of using `Invalidate()`. This will force the re-paint event to be called. Note that you may see a performance drop if you excessively repaint the screen.

```cs
    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isMoving)
        {
            mouseMovePosition = e.Location;
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, It Solveld the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any circles in your sample:)

I noticed your code was behaving a bit weird, when I added the following it seemed to make it run a bit better.

```
  this.pictureBox1.MouseClick += pictureBox1_MouseClick;
```

...

```
    void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        isMoving = false;
    }
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Don't put questions in your answers.