# Unable to display/hide label while a function executes

Tags: c#, function, response, invalidation

My code is as :

```
main()
{
    label1.Visible=true;

    /* code that takes about 1-2 minutes to respond */

    label1.Visible=false;
}
```

Now i am unable to display & hide that label.

How do I display and hide the label?

Comment: If you want to change a labels state while code is executing then you should consider multithreading.

Comment: The underlying cause is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/952964/60761). The `await` answer below is a better solution.

Comment: I think you need to call `Invalidate` and then `Update`. See [Control.Invalidate Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Just put `this.Refresh();` after hide/shod instuction

Answer (score 2):

It's because all work is done in one thread which is your `UI` thread. Try performing the hard work in another thread asynchronously:

```
async void YourMethod()
{
    label1.Visible=true;
    await Task.Run(() => /* do the work */); 
    label1.Visible=false;
}
```

See [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.

Comment: Note that YourMethod should be an eventhandler (`async void YourMethod(object sender, SomeEventArgs e)`) or you'll only have shifted the problem elsewhere.