# Undo the border i created with ControlPaint.DrawBorder()

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on WindowsForm C#.

The border i create becomes problem when maximized!

```
private void App_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, ClientRectangle, Color.Crimson, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
    }
```

Normal:
[image]

Maximized:
[image]

Am i doing something wrong?

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Seriously, you want us to debug a picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it my self :D

1) Create a button, turn its FlatStyle to flat.

2) Turn Enable property to false, also remove all text

3) Dock the button to fill.

4) If previous button,labels(control) got hidden because of button, right click  the button , send it to back!

Answer (score 2):

`DrawBorder()` has a parameter that can be used to remove a previously drawn border, just set `ButtonBorderStyle` to `None`

Example:

```
ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, (sender as Control).ClientRectangle, Color.Red, ButtonBorderStyle.None);
```

The only thing I don't like as much of my approach, is that it requires calls to the `Paint` event, which can get slow.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952964) to refresh the form at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided, I see it twice, meaning the painted information is being retained (relative to the position of the form) from the previous instance.

I'd strongly recommend staying away from trying to paint the non-client area.

If you have a custom request such as this, create a form with FormBorderStyle.None.  Then, have a custom event to paint the Split Container's border.  The top panel will have the custom min/max buttons.  The rest of the content should be in the lower panel that fills below the min/max button.

**Stay away from non-client painting.  It's more trouble than it's worth.**

Comment: Thanks i will follow the rule for rest of my coding journey.